# Gradient of time dependent function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $u\in L^2(\bar{\Omega})$ be a differentiable function which is also time-dependent, where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Is there any connection between $(\nabla u_t,\nabla u)$ and $(\nabla u,\nabla u)$. My final problem is to show the positivity of $(\nabla u_t,\nabla u)$.

I worked with a simple example of $d=1$ and taking $u(x,t)=x^2t$. Here, I get it as $(\nabla u_t,\nabla u)=t(\nabla u,\nabla u)$ with $\Omega=(0,1)$. Can we say it in general this holds? I mean can I say $(\nabla u_t,\nabla u)\geq0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $u(x,t)=e^{-t}x^2$ instead of $u(x,t)=x^2t$ in your example. Then
$$
(\nabla u_t,\nabla u)=-(\nabla u,\nabla u).
$$